# What element values should i select in order to click the element

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the html code snippet:

```
<div autoid="" buttondecorator="" class="ideas-card _ngcontent-zty-5 collapsed-card" aria-label="Find new keywords" aria-expanded="false" aria-describedby="F7C56A74-5C67-4B02-B3E2-AFD3DFBA318B--0" aria-hidden="false" id="F49F12F8-6C5C-4567-AAD9-6C76A52FD801--0" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></div>
```

From the above snippet code its is a card element and using selenium python I am trying to click that element.

My code is:

```
find_new = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Find new keywords']").click()
```

Is there any other methods to select that element?

The error message I am getting is :

```
element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: my html snippet <div autoid="" buttondecorator="" class="ideas-card _ngcontent-zty-5 collapsed-card" aria-label="Find new keywords" aria-expanded="false" aria-describedby="F7C56A74-5C67-4B02-B3E2-AFD3DFBA318B--0" aria-hidden="false" id="F49F12F8-6C5C-4567-AAD9-6C76A52FD801--0" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait for the element to become clickable before clicking on it. Use WebDriverWait and Expected Conditions:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

find_new = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Find new keywords']")).click()
```

Another trick you might try is using JavaScript Executor:

```
find_new = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Find new keywords']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", find_new)
```